# Выборка данных через Join агрегатные функции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы `dbo.application, dbo.action, dbo.ogpo_dept, dbo.employees`

```
| ID | dept_id | action | premium |    | ID | Name     |    
------------------------------------    -----------------      
| 1  | 5       | 21     | 61446   |    | 21 | Stiker   |    
| 2  | 11      | 18     | 325     |    | 18 | One Super|
| 3  | 5       | null   | 224     |
| 4  | 11      | 18     | 262     |

| ID | Name               |            | ID | FullName | dept_id |
---------------------------            ---------------------------
| 5  | Sales Dep          |            | 1  | Mike     | 5       |
| 11 | HR Dep             |            | 2  | Ronaldo  | 11      |
```

**Запрос:**

```
select od.name as dept_name,
       e.Fullname,
       oac.name,
       COUNT(oa.id) as total, 
       SUM(oa.premium) as premSum
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
     inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]
group by dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]
```

Запрос выполняется долго и так и не выводит результат. Я заметил, что, если в запросе убрать `SUM(oa.premium) as premSum`, то запрос выполняется успешно.

Ну в итоге результат должен быть:

```
| dept_name          | Fullname   | name      | total | premsum |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Sales Dep           | Mike       | Stiker    | 591   | 1556    |
|HR Dep              | Ronaldo    | One Super | 54    | 54544   |
|HR Dep              | Ronaldo    | null      | 5     | 4785545 |
```

Comment: можете изменить данные так, что бы данные  в верхнем примере (структура таблиц) совпадали с данными в  ожидаемой результате

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev, не могу изменить структуру

Comment: структуру не нужно менять. Просто в вопросе в начале есть структура таблиц. 1. нет название таблиц. Которое что. 2. в структура данные (Stiker, One Super) а в результате (Стикер, защита) этот пример сделать одинаковым. спасибо

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev, изменил структуру

Comment: Уточните, сколько записей в каждой таблице.
Если их много, то очевидно, что у Вас просто нет нужных индексов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым верным, конечно, будет посмотреть план выполнения. 
Но тут я бы предложил разобрать запрос по шагам и, заодно, скорректировать синтаксис.

Во-первых, проверьте, как работает запрос на подсчет суммы.

```
select od.name as dept_name,
    COUNT(oa.id) as total, 
    SUM(oa.premium) as premSum
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
    left join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
group od.name
```

Во-вторых, если данный запрос работает как надо и быстро, последовательно добавьте еще таблицу `action` с выводом нужного результата, а потом `employees`, выявляя когда возникает проблема.

В третьих, придерживайтесь какого-то одного стиля оформления запроса (это не влияет на выполнение, но просто рекомендация по хорошим практикам), а в группировке не заставляйте оптимизатор делать лишние действия (он ведь может Вас и не понять=)):

```
select od.name as dept_name,
   e.Fullname,
   oac.name,
   COUNT(oa.id) as total, 
   SUM(oa.premium) as premSum
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
   inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
   left join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
   left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.action
group by od.name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.action
```

И в-четвёртых, внимательно изучите Ваш запрос, в нем что-то явно не так с логикой. Смотрите, у Вас есть таблица `dbo.employees`, какое отношение она имеет к данному запросу? Она не используется ни в какой связи, а только при выводе имени. При этом получается, что если сотрудников будет несколько на один отдел, то сумма у Вас сразу удвоится/утроится/..., т.к.  `dbo.application` связана `dbo.ogpo_dept`, а не с `dbo.employees`.

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
select od.name as dept_name,
       e.Fullname,
       oac.name,
       COUNT(oa.id) as total, 
       SUM(coalesce(oa.premium,0)) as premSum
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
     inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action] AND oac.id IS NOT NULL
group by dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]
```

тут `coalesce` заменяет `null` на `0`

Comment: запрос висит не выполняется

Comment: может у вас данных много? если так, нужно индексацию делать

Comment: @ Saidolim Djuraev, данных не много, и еще если убрать             inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id то тогда работает с агрегатными функциями

Comment: может проблема тут? `left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]` попробуйте сделать `left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action] and oa.[action] is not null`

Comment: запрос должен выводить договора с акциями и без акции, т.е null тоже

Comment: но `left join` на `null` не правильно. тогда последний должен быть не `left join`

Comment: тогда как выбрать без акции и с акциями(с null)

Comment: @Zhandos я бы попробовал сделать два запроса один для с акциями другой без, поля я так понимаю одинаковые и потом сделал "union"

Comment: `left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action] AND oac.id IS NOT NULL` не помогло? Тут поменял `oac.id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev, не помагает, я могу вывести список договоров с акциями через inner join , но мне надо без  и с акциями